# PHP Legacy Support, stdClass issue

Tags: php, stdclass

I was recently handed some of our companies legacy PHP code to work with. There have been updates to the WSDL and API and PHP version (from 5.3 to 5.6) used with this product since the code worked and the code no longer works properly. Specifically;

```
  $response = $mySforceConnection->query($query);
  //var_dump($response);
  $out='<table><tr><th>Spec Name</th><th>Name</th><th>SF Number</th><th>MW</th></tr>';
foreach ($response->records as $record) {
  $out.='<tr><td>'.$record->fields->Spec->fields->Name.'</td>';
  $out.='<td>'.$record->fields->Spec->fields->Owner->fields->FirstName.' ';
  $out.=$record->fields->Spec->fields->Owner->fields->LastName.'</td>';
  $out.='<td>'.$record->fields->Spec->fields->Owner->fields->EmployeeNumber.'</td>';
  $out.='</table>';
  exit($out);}
```

Error out with;

```
[13-Apr-2017 09:42:52 US/Eastern] PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$fields in T:\sample.php on line 44
[13-Apr-2017 09:42:52 US/Eastern] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in T:\sample.php on line 44
```

The $record returned is;

```
object(stdClass)#8 (3) {
  ["type"]=>
  string(19) "SpecLineItem"
  ["Id"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    string(18) "00k6000000QX8E7AAL"
    [1]=>
    string(18) "00k6000000QX8E7AAL"
  }
  ["any"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Spec"]=>
    object(stdClass)#9 (3) {
      ["type"]=>
      string(11) "Spec"
      ["Id"]=>
      NULL
      ["any"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(74) "<sf:Name>Machineworks - National-Renewal-2015-01-01</sf:Name>"
        ["Owner"]=>
        &object(stdClass)#10 (3) {
          ["type"]=>
          string(4) "User"
          ["Id"]=>
          NULL
          ["any"]=>
          string(119) "<sf:EmployeeNumber>12345</sf:EmployeeNumber><sf:FirstName>John</sf:FirstName><sf:LastName>Doe</sf:LastName>"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Afraid this falls outside of my very limited PHP scope. How do I adjust the references in the $out construct to properly reference the data? Sorry for something that is likely so basic a question.

Comment: Other than this notice errors, does the app produce expected output or is it wrong? Its possible that these errors were always there just ignored and in new setup they are displayed. If it behaves as expected then http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php should help you, if it does not then the problem most likely is somewhere else and this is just an side effect.

Comment: No, after the error the code completes but I still dont have valid data I need to have those values display and they dont. And I am at a loss at how to get them. For example how do I get the employeeNumber? $record->fields->Spec->fields->Owner->fields->EmployeeNumber worked in the past but now with the errors.. I have tried to figure out how to pull it but...

Comment: That means the problem is with `$mySforceConnection->query($query);` but I can't tell anything more as I don't know what it is.